# Is it correct to say "you need to class up a little bit" or "you need to class it up a little bit"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

In the movie **Vacation Friends**, a couple goes **into/to** a wedding (not sure we say "**go into the wedding**" as they actually move into the house or hall where the wedding is held)

People **at/in** the wedding are quite polite (not sure we say "in the wedding" as they actually inside  house or hall where the wedding is held)

The couple is funny but uses a lot of bad words such as "**fart**", "**shit**", etc.

Then a man comes and he says to the couple "**you need to class it up a little bit**".

I don't see "**class up**" or "**class something up**".

SO I guess this is slang meaning "**you need to be in higher class**"

Answer (score 2):

1. To "go into a wedding" is to be either the bride or groom.  This phrase is extremely formal and possibly a little archaic.  To "go to a wedding" is to attend a wedding as a guest or witness.
2. To be "in a wedding" is to be part of the ceremony of the wedding.  The bride, groom, bridesmaids, groomsmen, flower girl, ushers, and officiant are all "in the wedding".  In contrast, "at the wedding" is simply at the location the wedding is held.

Now to your main question.

"To class up" means to act with a higher level of sophistication, or to act as if you were a higher class.  "To class  up" is the same, except with regards to a *specific* something.  In the phrase "you need to class it up", the "it" is referring to the language and word choice they are using.  "Fart" isn't necessarily a *bad* word, but it is a childish word, and a lower class word.  "Shit" is generally considered to be a bad word, as well as a lower class one.